# Set default fields

Tags: firebird, optimization, query-performance

Is there a way to inform the database that some fields are default (have always the same value) so that I don't need include them in all my queries?

Suppose:
Select ... where f1=a, f2=b, f3=c, f4=d

After preset f1 = a and f2 = b I have.

Select ... where f3=c, f4=d

To get the same return of the previous query

I don't have a clue if it is simple or impossible :-)

tkx all

Comment: Is it always the same query except tha values of f3 and f4? If so, you can use bind variables.

Comment: @psa do you mean that in the table, all the rows have the same value in column `f1`? If that's the case, you can have the column as calculated or `virtual`. It doesn't have to be stored at all.

Comment: @psa: would you be so kind to suplly mor information. What kind of database / application. What type of quey?  Why do you think that  a feature is useful?

Comment: miracle 173, I forgot to mention I'm using Firebird. The value of f1 and f2 are the same for one subset of the table (more than one table) and I want to perform updates on this subset of values. I'm working on a recursive thing so f1 and f2 are always the same and I need handle (query/delete/insert) only f3 and f4 without care f1 and f2 since they have the same value for a subset. I'm researching now ypercube tip (calculated and virtual) and it seems 'view' give the subset I want to handle but I'm not sure if I can apply updates in a view and could see other users insertions in that view that'

Comment: Is it a subset or the whole table that has these default values? If it's a subset, how do you expect `WHERE f3=c AND f4=d` to select rows from only this subset?

Comment: It's a subset. I expect to select f3=c and f4=d because I already preset (that's the issue) that f1=a and f2=b.

Comment: Would be like to open a section where I say: db in this section f1=a and f2=b always. On other section I would set f1=x and f2=y and so on.